# Show byte array image in WPF with high refresh rate

Tags: c#, wpf, image

### Context

I have a Basler camera that throw an event when a new image is captured.
In the event arg, I can get the image grabbed as a byte array.

I have to do computation on this image and then show it in a WPF application. The camera refresh rate is up to 40FPS.

### Issue and found solution

A solution to convert a byte array to a WPF image can be found here : [Convert byte array to image in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/15045363)
This solution is great to convert only one time the byte array, however I feel like there is a lot of memory loss to do it at 40FPS. A new BitmapImage() is created every time and can't be disposed.

**Would there be a better solution to display in WPF a byte array that changes up to 40 FPS ?** (the way the problem is handled can be completely rethought)

### Code

This solution to show the camera stream in WPF works, but the `BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();` line doesn't look good to me.

```
private void OnImageGrabbed(object sender, ImageGrabbedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the result
    IGrabResult grabResult = e.GrabResult;
    if (!grabResult.GrabSucceeded)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Grab error: {grabResult.ErrorCode} {grabResult.ErrorDescription}");
    }

    // Make process on the image
    imageProcessor.Process(grabResult);

    // Convert grabResult in BGR 8bit format
    using Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(grabResult.Width, grabResult.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptrBmp = bmpData.Scan0;
    converter.Convert(ptrBmp, bmpData.Stride * bitmap.Height, grabResult);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    // Creat the BitmapImage
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); // <-- never Disposed !
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memory.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = memory;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.EndInit();
        image.Freeze();
    }
    LastFrame = image; // View is binded to LastFrame
}
```

Comment: Do you run into issues? Why you think you don't [dispose it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8352787/1997232)?

Comment: A single WriteableBitmap shoud perform a lot better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about _code optimisations_ are off-topic. See _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_ and  _[Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help)_ for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a videostream from my webcam in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890103/displaying-a-videostream-from-my-webcam-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use a WriteableBitmap to display the result. This avoids the need to reallocate the UI image. If the pixel format in your source matches the one in the bitmap you can simply use [WritePixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.writepixels?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap_WritePixels_System_Windows_Int32Rect_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to update the image.

Note that you can only modify WriteableBitmap from the main thread, and the ImageGrabbed event will be raised on a background thread. And the grabResult will be disposed of once the event handler returns. So you will need to [ask the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300164/run-code-in-main-thread) to do the actual updating, and you will need a intermediate buffer for this. But this buffer can be pooled if needed.

An alternative might be to write your own loop, calling `RetrieveResult` repeatedly, this would let you dispose the grab results manually, after the UI has been updated. It might also be possible to keep a pool of WriteableBitmaps, I guess it should be safe to write to if it is not actually used by the UI.

Comment: _"first of all, BitmapImage actually `does not need disposing`, it will be collected by the GC just like any other managed object"_ - that's [not entirely corrrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532667/585968) and depends on **how** it was constructed.  Rest is fine +1

Answer (score 0):

On each frame, you are

- creating a Bitmap
- encoding it into a MemoryStream
- creating a BitmapImage
- decoding the MemoryStream into the BitmapImage

Better create a `WritableBitmap` once, and repeatedly call its `WritePixels` method.

You may still need to convert the raw buffer, since WPF does not seem to have an equivalent for `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` - or it is perhaps `PixelFormats.Bgr32`.

```
var wb = LastFrame as WriteableBitmap;

if (wb == null)
{
    wb = new WriteableBitmap(
        grabResult.Width, grabResult.Height,
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
    LastFrame = wb;
}

wb.WritePixels(...);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am in a similar situation:  Pulling live images off a camera and dumping them to the UI for "live" view.    I spent a good deal of time trying to find the most efficient solution.  For me, the turned out to be BitmapSource.Create.  I take the raw array of bytes (plus a structure describing image characteristics like width, height, etc) and use one function call to convert it to a BitmapSource.

Now in my case, the images are greyscale, 8-bit images so if you're trying to show colors, your arguments would be different. But here's a snippet of what I do.

```
public class XimeaCameraImage : ICameraImage
{
    public unsafe XimeaCameraImage(byte[] imageData, ImgParams imageParams)
    {
        Data             = imageData;
        var fmt          = PixelFormats.Gray8;
        var width        = imageParams.GetWidth();
        var bitsPerPixel = 8;   // TODO: Get ready for other image formats
        var height       = imageParams.GetHeight();
        var stride       = (((bitsPerPixel * width) + 31) / 32) * 4;
        var dpi          = 96.0;

        // Copy the raw, unmanaged, image data from the Sdk.Image object.

        Source = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            dpi,
            dpi,
            fmt,
            BitmapPalettes.Gray256,
            imageData,
            stride);

        Source.Freeze();
    }

    public           byte[]        Data { get; }
    public           BitmapSource  Source            { get; }
}
```